# java - Read zip entries inside of directory inside of zip file

Tags: java

I have this

```
 public static List<byte[]> readAllClasses(byte[] jarFile) {
    List<byte[]> classes = new ArrayList<>();
    List<ZipEntry> entries = readEntries(jarFile);

    for (ZipEntry entry : entries) {
        if (entry.isDirectory()) {
            //read entries inside of directory
        } else {
            classes.add(readZipEntry(jarFile, entry));
        }
    }
...
```

How can I read the entries inside a ZipEntry that is a directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to read the directory. All the entries will be returned.

For example you have zip file:

- file1
- folder

  - file2

`entries` will return

- file1
- folder/
- folder/file2